# I need to change the URL in some "favorites" links

Tags: powershell

We're changing the URL on 5 webshare sites so they only respond to HTTPS and FQDN requests.
A lot of our users have "internal" links in their favorites that will break when we change the URL's.

I need a way to open each 'Favorite' and see if any of the links point to the old URL and then change it to the new one.

This is what I'm trying to do (no error comes up, but the link is not modified):

```
    # Set folder variable
    $folder = $env:HOMEPATH + '\' + 'favorites'                                             #'

    # Backup the folder
    Copy-Item $folder $env:homepath\favorites1 -recurse

    # set the stringtofind variables
    $stringToFind1 = "http://wss1/"
$stringToFind2 = "http://iwds/"
$stringToFind3 = "http://webshare/"
$stringToFind4 = "http://mysites/"
$stringToFind5 = "http://eforms/"

    # Set the stringtoplace variables
$stringToPlace1 = "https://wss1.FQDN.com"
$stringToPlace2 = "https://iwds.FQDN.com"
$stringToPlace3 = "https://webshare.FQDN.com"
$stringToPlace4 = "https://mysites.FQDN.com"
$stringToPlace5 = "https://eforms.FQDN.com"

    # Execute the content changes
gci $folder\*.url -recurse | foreach-object { (Get-Content $_) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $stringToFind1, $stringToPlace1 } | Set-Content $_ }
gci $folder\*.url -recurse | foreach-object { (Get-Content $_) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $stringToFind2, $stringToPlace2 } | Set-Content $_ }
gci $folder\*.url -recurse | foreach-object { (Get-Content $_) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $stringToFind3, $stringToPlace3 } | Set-Content $_ }
gci $folder\*.url -recurse | foreach-object { (Get-Content $_) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $stringToFind4, $stringToPlace4 } | Set-Content $_ }
gci $folder\*.url -recurse | foreach-object { (Get-Content $_) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $stringToFind5, $stringToPlace5 } | Set-Content $_ }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use COM to manipulate shortcut files.  Use the [`CreateShortcut` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/xsy6k3ys.aspx) of the [`Shell` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aew9yb99.aspx) to read a shortcut file:

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObject 'WScript.Shell';
$shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut($shortcutPath);
```

Then you can read and modify the [`TargetPath` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/594k4c67.aspx), and commit the changes to the shortcut file using the [`Save` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/k5x59zft.aspx):

```
$oldTargetPath = $shortcut.TargetPath;
Write-Host "Shortcut currently points to $oldTargetPath";
$shortcut.TargetPath = $newTargetPath;
$shortcut.Save();
```

Comment: Very handy; just to state it explicitly: this approach can read/update/create regular shortcut files (`*.lnk`) as well as URL shortcut files (`*.url`) (favorites).

Answer (score 1):

The final code that works:

```
$favourites_path = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('Favorites') 
Copy-Item $favourites_path "$favourites_path`1" -Recurse
$favourites = Get-ChildItem $favourites_path -Recurse -Filter *.url
foreach ($favourite in $favourites) {

$shortcut = (New-Object -ComObject 'WScript.Shell').CreateShortCut($favourite.FullName)
$newpath=switch -Wildcard ($shortcut.TargetPath)
{
    'http://wss1/*'           { $_ -replace 'http://wss1', 'https://wss1.vmc.com'}
    'http://iwds/*'           { $_ -replace 'http://iwds', 'https://iwds.vmc.com'}
    'http://webshare/*'       { $_ -replace 'http://webshare', 'https://webshare.vmc.com'}
    'http://mysites/*'        { $_ -replace 'http://mysites', 'https://mysites.vmc.com'}
    'http://eforms/*'         { $_ -replace 'http://eforms', 'https://eforms.vmc.com'}
    default                   { $_ }
}

$shortcut.TargetPath=$newpath
$shortcut.Save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it by copying a folder of already created links and weed out the current ones so you would not have any trouble maintaining them in the future.

However, here's how to do it using your method, using Powershell. The code below uses Regular Expressions to do the work. It should satisfy your requirements.

```
$favourites_path = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('Favorites') 

Copy-Item $favourites_path "$favourites_path`1" -Recurse -Force

$favourites = Get-ChildItem($favourites_path) -Recurse -Filter *.url

$reg_path = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\'

$start_page = (Get-Itemproperty -Path $reg_path).'Start Page'

foreach ($favourite in $favourites) {

    $shortcut = (New-Object -ComObject 'WScript.Shell').CreateShortCut($favourite.FullName)

    $new_path = switch -Regex ($shortcut.TargetPath) {

        ('http://wss1/(.*)') { "https://wss1.FQDN.com/$($Matches[1])"; break }
        ('http://iwds/(.*)') { "https://iwds.FQDN.com/$($Matches[1])"; break }
        ('http://webshare/(.*)') { "https://webshare.FQDN.com/$($Matches[1])"; break }
        ('http://mysites/(.*)') { "https://mysites.FQDN.com/$($Matches[1])"; break }
        ('http://eforms/(.*)') { "https://eforms.FQDN.com/$($Matches[1])"; break }
        default { $_ }
    }

    $shortcut.TargetPath = $new_path

    # Set homepage
    if ($shortcut.TargetPath -eq $start_page) { Set-ItemProperty -Path $reg_path -Name 'Start Page' -Value $new_path }

    $shortcut.Save()
}
```

I have added the code to help you with setting the homepage.

Comment: Upon further testing I found the rest of the links missing. That's to say anything to the right of the base url is deleted. I.E. http://eforms/default.aspx is now https://eforms.fqdn.com. I need the rest of the url to stay intact.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the first script is that the -Path is required for the Set-Content Cmdlet. Here is a script I wrote which works.  You can adjust as needed.  It is fairly verbose but hey I'm learning. I called the script FindURLs.ps1
Note: The first version changed the CONTENT but NOT the URL argh..

```
param (
    [string]$string = "//hpenterprise",
    [string]$stringtoreplace = "//hpe",
    [string]$Path = "*.url",
    [switch]$Recurse = $false,
    [switch]$update = $false,
    [switch]$help = $false
)
$myargs = @{
  Path = $Path
  Recurse = $Recurse
}
#echo "$string $stringtoreplace $Path $Recurse $update"
#echo $myargs
#$help=$true;
if ($help) { 
    echo "
FindURLs Finds and Optionally Replaces URLs by default
string = $string   The string to find.
stringtoreplace = $stringtoreplace   The string to replace the found string
Path = $Path       Path to the urls
Recurse = $Recurse  Recurse option.  i.e. start in this directory and all recursively find URLs in sub-directories
Update = $update    Update the string.  This option must be used to actually update the URLs.

i.e. 
FindURLs.ps1                  will start in the current directory and check the URLs for $string and show what the new string will look like.
FindURLs.ps1 -Recurse         will find the strings and show new strings recursively.
FindURLs.ps1 -Recurse -Update will find the strings and update them recursively.

You can also override string, stringtoreplace and path.
For example -Path <new_path> -string //hpebrokenlinks -stringtoreplace //hpenewlinks
You may need to use quotes around <new_path> if the path contains any spaces.
Note: PowerShell is Case Insensitive unlike other shells.
"
    return;
}

Get-Childitem @myargs | ForEach-Object {
    $urlpath = $_.FullName
    echo "Examining  $urlpath"
    $shortcut = (New-Object -ComObject 'WScript.Shell').CreateShortCut($urlpath)
    if ($shortcut.TargetPath -Match $string) { 
        echo ("Changing   " + $shortcut.TargetPath)
        $shortcut.TargetPath = ForEach-Object { $shortcut.TargetPath -replace $string, $stringtoreplace }
        echo ("To         " + $shortcut.TargetPath)
        if ($update) { 
            #Set-Content -Path "$path" "$new_content" Does not Work!  Even though the code says it works.  Content changes but the link is the same?
            #Had to change to the shortcut method.

            $shortcut.Save();
            echo ("Updated To " + $shortcut.TargetPath)
        } else { 
            echo "-Update Option not set.  Test Only No Change to URL" 
        }
    }   else { 
        echo ("No Change  " + $shortcut.TargetPath)
    }
    echo ""
}
```